# Construction Of Minimal Set With Sum Property

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

A set $S$ of positive integers satisfies the following conditions:

- $1 \in S$ is the smallest element and $n \in S$ is the largest element in $S$.
- If $w \in S$ and $w > 1$, there exist $x, y, z \in S$ such that $w = x + y + z$.

**Problem:** What is the minimum number of elements $S$ can contain?

EDIT: I removed a wrong claim here. This problem seems to be known as finding the minimum cardinality of an addition chain and seems to be very difficult, even for the case where the second condition from above is replaced by $w = x + y$. The answers are known to OEIS: https://oeis.org/A079300.

In the above problem, $S$ must contain only odd numbers. Take the smallest even number $w \in S$. Since $w = x + y + z$ with $x, y, z \in S$ and $1 \le x, y, z < w$, all $x$, $y$ and $z$ must be odd. So $w$ is odd, contradiction.

If $1 = s_1 < s_2 < \dots < s_k = n$ denote the elements of $S$, it holds $\displaystyle s_i \ge \left\lceil \frac{s_{i + 1}}{3} \right\rceil$ for $1 \le i < k$. In case of $n$ being a power of $3$, these estimates are sharp and the answer is $1 + \log_3(n)$.

Note that I want to find the exact number. It is not necessary to obtain a closed-form expression though. I appreciate any help on this question.

Comment: Well, you know that $a(n) \leq \frac{n+1}{2}$, by induction: if $S(n)$ is the minimal set with maximum element $n$, in the inductive step you can take the set $S(n+2) = S(n) \cup \{n+2\}$ and that works as $n+2=n+1+1$. Of course this is only an upper bound, as $a(7) = 3$ and not $4$.

Comment: That is actually a pretty bad upper bound. Better take $S(6n + 3) = S(2n + 1) \cup \{ 6n + 3 \}$, $S(6n + 1) = S(6(n - 1) + 5) \cup \{ 6n + 1 \}$ and $S(6n + 5) = S(6n + 3) \cup \{ 6n + 3 \}$. This way, we obtain $a(n) \le 3 \log_3(n)$ which is much less than $\frac{n + 1}{2}$. But I'm interested in the exact number, as mentioned in the question.

Comment: Note that the second smallest element is $3= 1+1+1$, so with the scheme $n=1+3+(n-4)$, you get the bound $\lfloor \frac{n}4 \rfloor + 2$.

Comment: Yeah I know it doesn't help much, @neutron-byte,

Comment: Sorry if this is pedantic, but I'm not sure you're correct about the recursion in the case where the last property is instead w=x+y. Isn't a(1)=1 because S={1} works? And isn't a(2)=1 because S={1,2} works? But the recursion a(2n)=1+a(n) would say a(2)=2.

Comment: You're right, $a(1) = 1$, because we can take $S = \{  1 \}$ and $a(2) = 2$, because $S = \{ 1, 2 \}$. That's exactly what the recurrence yields: $a(2) = 1 + a(1) = 1 + 1 = 2$.

Comment: Have you tried computing the smallest size for small $n$'s by bruteforce with a computer, and then look up the sequence in OEIS ?

Comment: @neutron-byte: Ah yes, of course. My "combinatorial brain" was turned on and I was thinking of a(n) as *the number of possible sets* with maximum element n, not (as stated) the size of a smallest possible such set. Thanks.

Comment: @GabrielRomon: The sequence $a(n)$ is not known to OEIS. I provided the program here: https://gist.github.com/neutron-byte/270767aae3ad0bbcd1d14f9a566754b5. It computes the answers for $n < 130$ in a few seconds, but obviously becomes exponentially slow.

Comment: FWIW, if you are interested in the computation aspects of it, the "w = x+y" version of the problem (i.e. addition chain) is project euler problem no. 122,  https://projecteuler.net/problem=122 -- once you solved that puzzle numerically, you can access the discussion forum. 
 i have not solved 122 myself, but i have solved many other project euler puzzles, and in my experience there are often excellent algorithmic & implementation advice in the discussion forum.  hopefully some of that might apply to your "w = x+y+z" version.

Comment: Thank you for reference, along with another optimization I tried yesterday, my program turns out to solve it quite quickly. As expected, the discussion thread is interesting, but shows no groundbreaking algorithm or formula which takes polynomial time in the upper bound $n$. In the the Project Euler problem, the case $n = 191$ seems to be hardest, several people write this.

For the $w = x + y + z$ case, I have modest bounds and a program which may also work up to $n \le 200$ fast enough. This suffices with respect to what is known about the problem.